# Washing machined bounced from original position and stopped to work. What could be broken?

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine

Frigidaire stackable washer stopped to work one day in the middle of cycle. It had also bounced off from it's original position making loud noise - this has never happened before. It does not even turn on anymore. Dryer on the top still works as expected. Both share the same power source.

Since washer does not even turn on anymore, then I suspect that fuses (or some other safety mechanism) have blown off. However, since washer had bounced off from its original position then I also suspect that there must be a mechanic issue that must be troubleshooted together with fuses. **The first question I have is - Is this reasoning most likely correct that this can't be a simple fuse situation alone since the washer had bounced off from original position?**

However, I removed the front cover and tried to spin the belt with hand and I was able to move it in one direction with ease. The other direction not so much, but still seemed to spin. **The second question I have is - Is this expected behavior that belt spins with ease only in one direction because there are gears and/or clutch in the highlighted part or is the highlighted part most likely the one that is broken and needs to be replaced?**

[image: Highlighted part]

**Update#1: Picture of control panel (Frigidaire/Electrolux fex831fs2)**

[image]

Comment: washing machines can "walk around" if they have an unbalanced load in the tub.  the circled part is the gearbox it differentiates between wash and spin motions based on the direction that the motor is running.

Comment: @Jasen Interesting point. So the idea is that "unbalanced load" can get washing machine in a state where it would refuse to turn on until reset? I was able to find reset instruction for GE washing machines, but not mine - Frigidaire fex831fs2. Do you know how to reset mine mode? I added picture of control panel in case it helps. Also, I could not find reference to reset instructions in manual.

Comment: yeah i've seen washing machines shut down due to imbalance. usually turning the power off and then on again resets them.  it could be that one of the wires has broken internally come loose due to the vibrations.  that paper in the foregound probably holds the some of the details on what's inside this one.

Comment: @Jasen thanks, you were spot on. Drum had partially snapped one of the wires that go to door switch.

Comment: @Jasen, post your comment as an answer, you got it. Good call.

Comment: @Jasen, yes, please post your comment as answer. I will move pictures from mine answer to yours to document this particular case. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unbalanced load caused drum to bounce against that sharp edge. This snapped one of the wires that go to the door latch switch. With that wire snapped washing machine's controller thought that doors were open all the time and refused to start the cycle.

[image]

After, cutting the wire and splicing it, washing machine now works as expected.

Comment: Interesting problem. Glad you found a solution. I think you need to accept your answer to remove the bounty and keep the system from promoting this question.