# Washer makes humming noise, does not agitate, but can drain and fill water?

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine

This is the same Frigidaire FEX831FS4 washer and dryer combo which few weeks ago due to unbalanced load the switch wire had snapped. [I spliced the wire back together](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/132733/washing-machined-bounced-from-original-position-and-stopped-to-work-what-could) and washer worked again for a month.

However, the washer again stopped to work in the middle of cycle while it was full with water. This time it was small load. Washer was completely unresponsive until a small click, like relay, is heard coming either from door lock or most likely motor area (not yet 100% sure which one). When that click happens I am able to fast forward to the end of cycle and washer was able to drain all the water from the drum. And after attempting to start a new cycle it was able to fill with water, but it won't ever spin. After filling with water, the washer again becomes unresponsive until the same click happens again.

Also, the knob on front controller board (where is timer) has started to make this [strange humming noise](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNuWTFGuD9HzXiC0QWE-26iBSDW2jWRxOdGABBVXtxxbLEUlyIKrg9zie_PgABnbQ/photo/AF1QipMMOE5bW13--wIk9Mb1eDhGh-nrs5tDf4Tw7Cvb?key=b011YWJUUXhEWVJfakpxb0ZqSEdKeG5POTJPNjFn), which makes me think that motor may be still be good and that the washer could be repairable.

**What could it be the root cause this time? Why the strange humming noise coming from that knob? Could it be that this is another issue creeping up due to unbalanced load that happened month ago - I remember that the wire that snapped appeared a little burnt in the are - possibly because of touching the washer frame.**

Comment: Pressure switch , out of balance switch or timer . You could try to replace the wire you spliced - maybe you have a broken insulation somewhere that is shorting the unit out ??

Comment: @Ken Curious, can faulty pressure switch cause problems other than not filling drum with water at all or overfilling? If so, how? I will post pictures of my splice and also wiring diagram. What is "out of balance switch or timer"?

Comment: @Ken it seems that one of the connectors going to motor capacitor might have gotten off it. Not 100% sure yet because I noticed that wire is off when I tried to remove the cover behind which the capacitor is hidden and before turning on I touched also other wires. However, now the washer works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Just an FYI Pressure switch determines washer has correct amount of water to start cycle. Out of balance switch usually on top rear of washer tub just like an unbalanced tire the tub will swing out to one side really far (inertia) and hit that switch (turn unit off), sometimes it needs to be manually reset. Timer is a rotating switch that sets the modes, newer units might have an electronic control board for the timer. Be careful around capacitors they store electricity and can kill if handled improperly, discharge them before handling.